# Inner DIV fixed on Scrollable outer DIV

Tags: html, css

[image]

**Red Box** - my Container
**Blue Box** - left fixed table column

**Image Description:**

Blue Box: this div contains a table, it contains only those columns that i wanted to be fixed.

Red Box: this is the container of the whole table.

Basically wanted to have a fixed right columns, will be porting this into a plugin in jQuery.

But for now im gonna make a static one first with html and css

**The Problem:**
Well as seen in the image, the fixed div seems to overlap with the scrollable container where it resides, basically i wanted it to be relative to the scroll port or something so that it can be scrolled vertically and fixed horizontally

Why wouldn't i be using some other plugin?.. well my data that i will be putting into it is somewhat complicated to do when using those plugin. tailoring it would be time consuming.. maybe if i have time i can tailor some open source one..

Please see my source below

View File

```
<div class="row table-wrapper">
<div class="pinned-column">
     <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4">
                    <div align="right">
                        Fixed Data Header 1
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4">
                    <div align="right">
                        Fixed Data Header 1
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <div style="width: 110px;">
                        FD Header 1
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div style="width: 110px;">
                        FD Header 2
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div style="width: 110px;">
                        FD Header 3
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div style="width: 110px;">
                        FD Header 4
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php 
                for ($x = 0; $x < $GLOBAL_COUNT_x; $x++)
                {
            ?>
                    <tr>
            <?php 
                    for ($i = 0 ; $i < 4; $i++)
                    {
            ?> 
                        <td>
                            <div style="width: 70px;">
                                <?= 'Data '.($i+1) ?>
                            </div>
                        </td>
            <?php
                    }
            ?>
                    <tr>
            <?php 
                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">
                <div align="right">
                    Fixed Data Header 1
                </div>
            </th>
            <?php 
                for ($i = 0 ; $i < $GLOBAL_COUNT; $i++)
                {
            ?> 
                    <th>
                        <div style="width: 70px;">
                            <?= 'H'.($i+1) ?>
                        </div>
                    </th>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">
                <div align="right">
                    Fixed Data Header 1
                </div>
            </th>
            <?php 
                for ($i = 0 ; $i < $GLOBAL_COUNT; $i++)
                {
            ?> 
                    <th>
                        <div style="width: 70px;">
                            <?= 'H'.($i+1) ?>
                        </div>
                    </th>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div style="width: 110px;">
                    FD Header 1
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div style="width: 110px;">
                    FD Header 2
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div style="width: 110px;">
                    FD Header 3
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div style="width: 110px;">
                    FD Header 4
                </div>
            </th>
            <?php 
                for ($i = 0 ; $i < $GLOBAL_COUNT; $i++)
                {
            ?> 
                    <th>
                        <div style="width: 70px;">
                            <?= 'D'.($i+1) ?>
                        </div>
                    </th>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
            for ($x = 0; $x < $GLOBAL_COUNT_x; $x++)
            {
        ?>
                <tr>
        <?php 
                for ($i = 0 ; $i < $GLOBAL_COUNT + 4; $i++)
                {
        ?> 
                    <td>
                        <div style="width: 70px;">
                            <?= 'Data '.($i+1) ?>
                        </div>
                    </td>
        <?php
                }
        ?>
                <tr>
        <?php 
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS file

```
/*
 * Common
 */
.table-wrapper{
    height: 450px; 
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
/*
 * right-table(right side)
 * 
 */
.pinned-column{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px; 
    background-color: white;
}

/*
 * pinned-table (left side)
 * 
 */
```

Comment: Kindly save it as html file content and fiddle it pls. I cannot find the solutions